# Highcharts "stemWidth" not working with FF

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I needed to create a error bar style chart with HighCharts. The issue is, I want to remove the connecting verticle line(stem) to error points (whiskers).

Following is the code I used in errorbar section.

```
stemWidth: -1,
whiskerLength: 150
```

Following is a modified example from HighCharts examples to accomplish my requirement.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ry8qw/2/
```

This is working fine with Chrome. But not working with the FireFox (Version 20.0.1). I'm running the latest available FF version.

Are there any workarounds for this issue ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a issue, so I've reported to our developers here:https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1833

But you can use small workaround, iterate in each errorbar and change strike width by svg attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/ry8qw/6/

```
$.each(chart.series[1].data,function(i,data){
        data.stem.attr({
        "stroke-width":0
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I also able to fix this by setting "stemColor:'none'".